# How to highlight other square brackets in custom major mode?

Tags: regular-expressions, font-lock, syntax-highlighting, rx

I'm working in a custom major mode, and part of the syntax are the square brackets, like `[Hello world]` and so they can contain nested square brackets as in `[Hello [World]]`, however I see this problem were Emacs will highlight the inner most square bracket first.

This is the current rx expression I have come with using some external help:

```
(rx (submatch-n 1 "[" (submatch-n 2 (+ (not (any ?[ ?])))) "]"))
```

It does the job, but I prefer that it match the outer most square bracket first.

Comment: It's hard to do using plain regexp:s. If you use code instead, you can find the first and use `sexp-forward` to find the closing. The next step is to manufacture a match-data, so that you can match the brackets using subexpression font-lock highlights.

Comment: For example: https://github.com/Lindydancer/objc-font-lock

Comment: Let me review that, brb.

Comment: @Lindydancer please make your comment an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to match nested parenthesis pairs using plain regexp:s. If you use code instead, you can find the first and use `forward-sexp` to find the closing. The next step is to manufacture a match-data, so that you can match the brackets using subexpression font-lock highlights.

The following example is from [obj-font-lock](https://github.com/Lindydancer/objc-font-lock), a package the highlight Objective-C function calls:

```
(defun objc-font-lock-match-bracket (lim)
  "Search for an Objective-C method call.

Return non-nil if one is found. The point will be placed after
the start brace. The match data will be filled with the following:

   0 -- The entire method call
   1 -- The start brace
   2 -- The object expression
   3 -- The end brace.

Note that this function is intended to be used by font-lock, and
assumes that comments and string have been fontified."
  (let ((ok nil)
        (beg-of-expr nil)
        (end-of-expr nil))
    ;; Look for "[":s, but skip those that are used for array constructs.
    (while
        (progn
          (setq ok (re-search-forward "\\[" lim t))
          (and ok
               ;; Continue searching, if this bracket isn't suitable.
               (or (objc-font-lock-is-in-comment-or-string)
                   ;; When the `[' doesn't match a `]', skip it.
                   ;; Without this, code after the method call would
                   ;; be fontfied, typically up the the next closing
                   ;; brace.
                   (save-excursion
                     (goto-char (match-beginning 0))
                     (condition-case nil
                         (progn
                           (forward-sexp)
                           (not (eq (char-before) ?\] )))
                       (error nil)))
                   ;; Skip array subscripts.
                   ;;
                   ;; Record the start end end location of the first
                   ;; complex expression, in case this wasn't an array
                   ;; construct.
                   (save-excursion
                     (objc-font-lock-skip-whitespace-etc)
                     (setq beg-of-expr (point))
                     (objc-font-lock-skip-complex-expression)
                     (setq end-of-expr (point))
                     (objc-font-lock-skip-whitespace-etc)
                     (eq (following-char) ?\]))))))
    (if ok
        (let* ((beg (- (point) 1))
               (end (save-excursion
                     (goto-char beg)
                     (forward-sexp)
                     (point))))
          ;; This synthesized match data will be in place for the
          ;; highlights of the keyword as well as when the pre- and
          ;; post-match-forms of the anchored rule are executed.
          (set-match-data (list
                           ;; Match 0: Full range
                           beg end
                           ;; Match 1: [
                           beg (+ beg 1)
                           ;; Match 2: expr
                           beg-of-expr end-of-expr
                           ;; Match 3: ]
                           (- end 1) end))))
    ok))
```